# When to use optional value (?) and when associative value (!) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

```
let strName: String! = nil

let strFirstName: String? = nil
```

I am getting confused when use optional value and when use associative value. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Declaring a variable with ! indicates that at the declaration moment it's value is nil but you're SURE THAT it will be initialized before use it on your code.

Declaring with ? means that the variable is nil and you're not sure if it will have any value at any moment of the app execution.

Answer (score 1):

The `!` operator tells the compiler that a value **DOES** exist in that variable. The `?` tells the compiler that a value of that type **MIGHT** exist or may be **NIL**. Using `!` means `Unwrapping` that variable. It has it's own risk of crashing the app if not used properly. When you are unsure that when you unwrap an `optional` variable a value will exist or no, use `?` and unwrap it like so:

```
var someOptional: Int? = 100

if let anotherVar = someOptional{
print(anotherVar) //You have your unwrapped optional
}
else{
print(someOptional) //Nil if 100 is removed
}
```

Now try deleting the 100. You'll see a `nil`. That's how optionals work.